# Symfony: The _controller value maps to class, but this class was not found. Create this class or check the spelling

Tags: symfony

I am quite new in Symfony.
I am having this mistake and I know that there is a spelling problem. It should be Advert instead of Adert but I do not know in which part of the code, I can change it. I looked up everywhere I imagined.
Here is my AdvertController.php
Thanks a lot!

```
<?php
//src/Neo/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php
namespace Neo\PlatformBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $url= $this->get('router')->generate(
        'neo_platform_view', //first argument : path name
        array('id' => 5)
      );
        return new Response("The url of the announcement is:".$url);
    }
public function viewAction($id)
{
  return $this->render('NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:view.html.twig', array('id' => $id));
}
public function addAdction(Request $request)
{
  $session = $request->getSession();
  $session->getFlashBag()->add('info' , 'Announcement well saved');
  $session->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Yes yes, it has been saved!');
  return $this->redirectToRoute('neo_platform_view', array('id' => 5));
}
?>
```

[image: adert]

Comment: You have a typo in your routing file: `AdertController` instead of `AdvertController`

Comment: Indeed. It was in the file PlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All routes are loaded via a single configuration file - usually

```
app/config/routing.yml (see Loading Routes).
```

However, if you use routing annotations, you'll need to point the router to the controllers with the annotations. This can be done by "importing" directories into the routing configuration: